# iOS How to create a custom image picker/browser

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I have been looking around and haven't found a good answer for this.

Instagram uses an image browser/picker like [image: this].  As you can see above the images from the photo gallery are displayed in a grid below and you can directly choose image from there instead of using the default image picker layout.

The Groupme app also does something similar.[image: Like this].

Where images are displayed in a horizontal scrollable list and you can just choose from this.

I have been reading up on the image picker and the documentation says that subclassing is not support.

So my question is:

How do you create something like this?
If this is just a custom view that loads the images stored on the device.  How do I access those images?

I just need a starting point and what to specifically look for (custom browser/image picker etc).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the `ALAssetsLibrary` APIs, [docs here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html).